# Have Prometheus send a SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, monitoring, prometheus

I'm trying to use [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) to monitor my MySQL database but can't seem to find an area to add SQL queries. For example, I'd like to run a SQL query which returns a value and then add that value to the graph/send an alert. Is there a way to have Prometheus send SQL queries and retrieve the output?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://github.com/chop-dbhi/prometheus-sql will allow queries to be run against any SQL database that can then be scraped as metrics.

Comment: Great, thank you. And thanks for Prometheus, nice tool!

Comment: Just noticed that SQLAgent requires Docker. Is there a way to run this without it?

Comment: @brian-brazil ,  Can you help me on how to use sql-agent without using Docker?